# Algebra Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The expression $x^2-4x+5$ is a factor of $ax^3+bx^2+25$. Express the sum a+b as an integer.

Please give an explanation of how the answer

Comment: $$\frac{a x^3+b x^2+25}{x^2-4x+5}=4a+b+a x+\frac{(11a+4b)x-5(4a+b)+25}{x^2-4x+5}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\rm\ 0 = a\ x^3 + b\ x^2 + 25 - (x^2 - 4\ x + 5)\ (a\ x + 5) = (4\ a + b - 5)\ x^2 + (20 - 5\ a)\ x\ \Rightarrow \ a,\: b = \ldots$

Note: $\rm\ a\ x + 5\ $ comes from comparing leading and constant coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

If $x^2-4x+5$ is a factor of $ax^3+bx^2+25$, then $ax^3+bx^2+25=(x^2-4x+5)(\text{something})$.  Since $ax^3+\cdots$ is a polynomial of degree 3 and $x^2-\cdots$ is a polynomial of degree 2, the "something" must be a polynomial of degree 1:
$$ax^3+bx^2+0x+25=(x^2-4x+5)(\underline{\;\;\;\;\;\;}x+\underline{\;\;\;\;\;\;})$$
Try to fill in the two blanks based the terms on the left side that don't have $a$ and $b$ in them (for example, how will $+25$ end up in the product?), then finish the multiplication to find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

$ax^3+bx^2+25=(x^2-4x+5)(ax+k)$ , $k$ = constant

$ax(x^2-4x+5) + k(x^2-4x+5) =0$

$ax^3 + x^2(k-4a)+x(5a-4k)+5k=0$ 
compare to original then $5k=25 \implies k=5$ 
and $(5a-4k)=0$ so $a =4$ 
and $b= k-4a = 5 -16 =-11$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2-4x+5=0$ has the roots $2 \pm i$ they must also be roots of $ax^3+bx^2+25\,$ therefore:

$$
0 = a(2+i)^3+b(2+i)^2+25=8a -6a + 4b - b + 25 + i\,(12 a -a + 4b) \\
\iff
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
2a + 3b + 25 = 0 \\
11 a + 4b = 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Why did you post at  an answered question of 6 years ago?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I didn't go looking for it 6 years back, but user405235 added an answer yesterday before mine, which resurrected the question to the main page.

Comment: Wish the anonymous downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: I left comment.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I replied to *that* comment thinking it was made out of curiosity, but did not imagine that it was in fact deprecatory. That said, I don't see what you find wrong with anyone replying to *any* question that is still listed and active on MSE, regardless of how old. If you have a problem with the *contents* of my answer then by all means please point that out.

Comment: Also, anonymous is you. You didn't look what active question is.  Even if my english is poor, I can always communicate with everyone except you.  Your excuse bore me. The enough suspects about you difinitely made me downvote.

Comment: It was right that you edit the answer of new user. -10.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki `It was right that you edit the answer of new user` Sorry, no idea what that's supposed to mean. What I posted was my own answer, a mathematically valid answer, and entirely different from all other posted answers. That said, I am done here and bye.